# JComboBox - ActionPerformed - How to tell the difference between the user & code?

Tags: java, actionlistener, jcombobox

I have a number of `JComboBoxes` in a Java Gui application.

I would like to trigger events when the combo boxes are changed by the user (I have this done, and this works great).

My problem is that I also need to occasionally update the values in the combo boxes via code, and I don't want those same events to execute.

How do I tell the difference if its code, or a user, triggering those listeners?

Comment: Generally speaking, you can't.  The methods used to change the selected item (that you would call) are also called by the UI delegate in response to user interaction. You could set a flag(s) that would indicate to listeners that the state change is been performed programmatically and that they should ignore those updates (or take what ever special actions you want), but it is a little messy and you would need to take special care to ensure the flags are rest when you're done or you  could break you application

Comment: That's not really the answer I wanted to here, but it sounds like its probably the correct answer. If you'd like to post that as the answer, I'll go ahead and accept it. I assume with 46.5k reputation, you know what you're talking about.

Comment: Don't assume anything, I live by the moto "Fake it till you make it" ;) - Let's see if any one else comes up with a better idea.  In fact, in response to next question, I did.  You could use [`JComboBox#putClientProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#putClientProperty%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) to store the "flag" state, this makes it a "little" cleaner as you don't need some kind of "global" flag or custom combo box...

Answer (score 1):

> How do I tell the difference if its code, or a user, triggering those listeners?

```
comboBox.removeActionListener(...);
// do your code here
comboBox.addActionListener(...);
```